# Django react integration Trouble when dist is not immediate child of frontend folder which has pages

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, integration

We are building different pages so each has different folder inside frontend, but when we put the contents of sign up folder in front end folder directly and do npm run build, then removing sign up in path join expression in settings.py, then its working.
why is it so? How to fix?

[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWYzh.jpg)

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ2OZ.png)